# Desafio em C. dúvida

Tags: c

**O desafio é o seguinte:**

Na universidade de hackerlandia tem a seguinte política de notas :

- Todo estudante recebe uma **nota** que pode variar de **0** a **100**.
- Toda **nota** menor que **40** é uma nota vermelha.

Sam é professor na universidade e gosta de arredondar as **notas** de cada aluno de acordo com essas regras:

- Se a diferença entre a nota e o próximo múltiplo de **5**.
- Se o valor da **nota** for menor que **38**, não ocorre arredondamento, pois a nota será vermelha.

Por exemplo, **nota = 84** será arredondada para **85**, mas 29 não será arredondado já que é menor que **40**.

As entradas do programa são **N** número de notas e **num** o valor das notas.

O meu programa não funciona quando a variável **N** é maior ou igual a **4**. Se alguém puder me ajudar agradeço.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
//    define as variáveis N : numero de notas, num: valor das notas, r : resto da divisão por 5
    int N, num[N], r;

    scanf ("%i", &N);

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        scanf ("%i", &num[i]);
    }

//    essa estrutura 'for' serve para ver qual 'num' (valor da nota) será arredondado
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
//            define o espaço em que 'num' está contido (0 <= num <= 100)
            if (num[i] < 0 || num[i] > 100) {
            printf ("erro");
            return (0);
        }
        if (num[i] >= 38) {
            r = num[i] % 5;
            if (r > 5) {
                r = r - 5;
            }
            switch (r) {
            case (0) :
                break;
            case (1) :
                break;
            case (2) :
                break;
            case (3) :
                num[i] = num[i] + 2;
                break;
            case (4) :
                num[i] = num[i] + 1;
                break;
            }

        }
        else
            num[i] = num[i];
    }

//    imprime o resultado das notas depois de arredondadas quando preciso
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            printf ("%i\n", num[i]);
    }


    return (0);

}
```

Comment: Coloque a declaração `int num[N]` **após** a leitura de `N`. Este teste: `r = num[i] % 5; if (r > 5) { r = r - 5;}` não tem sentido pois `r` sempre irá variar entre 0 e 4 (vide definição do operador módulo `%`).

Answer (score 0):

O erro ocorre porque você está declarando o `array` de tamanho variável antes de inicializar esta variável. Segue o código corrigido.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  //    define as variáveis N : numero de notas, num: valor das notas, r : resto
  //    da divisão por 5
  int N, r;

  scanf("%i", &N);

  int num[N];

  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    scanf("%i", &num[i]);
  }

  //    essa estrutura 'for' serve para ver qual 'num' (valor da nota) será
  //    arredondado
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    //            define o espaço em que 'num' está contido (0 <= num <= 100)
    if (num[i] < 0 || num[i] > 100) {
      printf("erro");
      return (0);
    }
    if (num[i] >= 38) {
      r = num[i] % 5;
      if (r > 5) {
        r = r - 5;
      }
      switch (r) {
        case (0):
          break;
        case (1):
          break;
        case (2):
          break;
        case (3):
          num[i] = num[i] + 2;
          break;
        case (4):
          num[i] = num[i] + 1;
          break;
      }

    } else
      num[i] = num[i];
  }

  //    imprime o resultado das notas depois de arredondadas quando preciso
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    printf("%i\n", num[i]);
  }

  return (0);
}
```